# WebRTC crash AbstractMethodError due to the method onTrack in the PeerConnection Observer

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I use Intel webRtc. Connection is successful but this error occurs when the call is started and click on publish button.

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void
> org.webrtc.PeerConnection$Observer.onTrack(org.webrtc.RtpTransceiver)"
>
> E/rtc: Fatal error in:
> gen/sdk/android/generated_base_jni/jni/../../../../../../../third_party/webrtc/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.h,
> line 38
> A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16744 (signaling_threa)

Comment: Hello Sahar. Did you solve this issue? We have the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Elletlar yes i resolved this. by change my build gradle  to this version com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1

Comment: Did you upgrade your version number to a newer one or downgrade it from a newer to an older one? I am currently using 3.5.2 which is newer than 3.4.1, but still it requires additional changes to solve this problem.

Comment: My gradle version was 3.5.2. And I had this problem.But when I changed the version to 3.4.1, this problem solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have built up a preliminary understanding of this issue.

Firstly, we should have a look at Google's WebRTC source code:

```
public interface Observer {
    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onAddStream(MediaStream var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onRemoveStream(MediaStream var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onDataChannel(DataChannel var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onRenegotiationNeeded();

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver var1, MediaStream[] var2);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onTrack(RtpTransceiver transceiver) {
    }
}
```

If you notice 'onTrack' is the only method in the `interface` that has a default method implementation. It has "{}" after instead of ";". This feature called "default methods" was added to Java interfaces in Java 8.

Now the error we are getting, "AbstractMethodError" is probably because the JNI code is not Android 8 aware and is expecting the client code to implement all the methods in the interface...

I initially solved this problem and restored working WebRTC calls to my app by adding an implementation of the method:

```
private class Peer implements SdpObserver, PeerConnection.Observer {
     ...

     @Override
     public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {}

     @Override
     public void onTrack(RtpTransceiver transceiver) {}    
}
```

However, I think the real solution is to ensure all the code in the project is using Java 1.8:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

If anyone can shed more light on why this happens I would be grateful.

EDIT:

This problem can also be solved by changing the Gradle version, from `3.5.2` to `3.4.1` for example, but other combinations may work also.